# Javascript variables should retain same value of a variable,declared and initialized before

Tags: javascript, jsp, persistence

I need to save the value of a variable in `Javascript` which is declared and assigned value during previous call to the function in javascript. I am both declaring and initializing the variable only once, but I need to get the value of a variable when I needed. Is there is any way to store the value of variable and retrieve it, any time as I needed??

**p1.jsp**

```
<table>
     <% 
       for(i=0;i<g;i++){
           request.getSession().setAttribute("incr",i);
     %>
     <tr><td><jsp:include page="/p2.jsp" /></tr></td>
     <%}%>
</table>
```

**p2.jsp**

```
 <%!int i;%>
    <%
      i=request.getSession().getAttribute("incr");
    %>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var k<%=i%>;
    function d(){
         k<%=i%>=5;
    }
    </script>
```

//Here, i need to print k0,k1,.... value as i needed

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Are you trying to use this variable only within the duration that one particular browser page is displayed or do you want this value to persist across multiple page loads.  The easiest answer is very different depending upon the answer to that question.

Comment: I need to save my value across multiple pages

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: IE and Chrome browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage or localStorage to save the data as you need.
For example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("variable",value);
```